# excel date picker control

Tags: excel, datepicker, excel-2010, vba

I need to create an in cell date picker for a excel worksheet I'm creating.

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4za48s1h?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

However i cant understand how the example is supposed to place a calendar picker in cell `A1:C1`. In my worksheet, if i paste the code as is, it throws an error. if i try to modify it like so:

```
'Declaration
Public Function AddDateTimePicker(range As range, name As String) As DateTimePicker   

Private Sub ExcelRangeAddDateTimePicker()
Dim DateTimePicker1 As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.DateTimePicker
DateTimePicker1 = Me.Controls.AddDateTimePicker(Me.range("A1", "C1"), "DateTimePicker1")       
End Sub
```

I get no result at all...

Any tip or answer is appreciated :)

Comment: See http://www.rondebruin.nl/calendar.htm for a working example  .... I think your current link is not `VBA`

Comment: Thank you for an example, however i have used Ro de Bruin example this method requires the calendar to be installed. (in excel 2010 this calendar control is no longer automatically installed). The example page i included has examples in both C# and VB.

Comment: The example in not `VBA`.It may be `VB.Net`

Comment: Ok, but it is supposed to work in Excel, any clue to how this is done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a better example for a working Excel 2010 Calander than what i had discovered previously.

This Tutorial is really good, and helps you to create a pop up Calander for Excel 2010:
http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut07.htm

I found it at the bottom of the page linked by brettdj. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

This VBA version from Trevor Eyre looks pretty great and is well documented. One line of code opens the VBA form and gets the date:

```
myDate = CalendarForm.GetDate
```

http://trevoreyre.com/portfolio/excel-datepicker/

-OO-

Comment: Important note: When I ran the downloaded zip against VirusTotal 2 possible malwares were reported. Sorry for down-voting the answer. I have contacted the author about this issue.